# How to compare rows with the same 'Id' and drop rows with higher 'Dist' in Pandas DataFrame using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare rows having same 'Id' and then drop row which is having higher 'Dist'. There can be multiple rows with same 'Id'.
I have attached sample dataframe for reference.

[image]

I tried iterating over rows and compare but not able to achieve it.
Thanks for help and suggestion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use if need drop all maximum rows per groups:

```
df['Dist'] = df['Dist'].astype(float)

out = df[df['Dist'].ne(df.groupby('Id')['Dist'].transform('max'))]
```

If need drop only one maximum row per groups:

```
out = df.drop(df.groupby('Id')['Dist'].idxmax())
```

If need minimal row per group:

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby('Id')['Dist'].idxmin()]
```

Comment: In 'out' I will not get rows having unique 'Id'. Here its only returning rows where there are multiple value of same 'Id'.

Comment: @fluorine - So dont need `compare rows having same 'Id' and then drop row which is having higher 'Dist'.` ?

Comment: @fluorine - So if 3 rows per groups and remove row with maximum value `dist` get 2 rows.

Comment: if there are multiple rows with same 'Id', then I need to keep row with minimum 'Dist'. If there is unique 'Id' , then will keep it as it is.

Comment: above script is working nicely , but it excluding, rows with unique 'Id', in this case its excluding '5'

Comment: @fluorine - Understand. So need `out = df.loc[df.groupby('Id')['Dist'].idxmin()]`, right?